# Image of $T:M_n(F)\to M_n(F)$ s.t. $ T(A)=A+A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:M_n(\mathbb{F})\to M_n(\mathbb{F})$ s.t. $T(A)=A+A^T$. Show that $T$ is a linear transforation and find the kernel and the image of $T$.

My attempt:
I showed that this is a linear transformation and that its kernel is the set of skew symmetric matrices. but I couldn't find the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the matrix $A+A^T$ is symmetric so $\operatorname{Im}T\subset S_n(F)$, and conversely if $B\in S_n(F)$ then $T(\frac12 B)=B$ so we get the other inclusion and then the equality.